# How to record the vm screen with libvirt in python?

Tags: python, kvm, libvirt

I'm doing testautomation with python where I'm working with various hosts on a kvm server. To achieve this, I'm using libvirt and python3. Now I want to record the tests to see whats going on afterwards.

I tried something like

```
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open("...")
vm = conn.lookupByName('win10')
stream = conn.newStream()
while True:
    img = vm.screenshot(stream, 0)
    ....
```

but this only renders about 9 images per second, thus its very laggy. Is there a way get this done faster / more performant?

The virtual machines are set to use the spice display server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the VM has a VNC server configured, it would be far more effective to open a connection to VNC and receive the screen updates on the fly that way, pushed from the server. I wouldn't be surprised if there's already python code that exists somewhere to connect to VNC and record to a video stream.  If not, the 'gtk-vnc' library exports its API via python  and could be used to build such a tool.